# Raspberry pi to arduino with nrf24 - RF24 library examples not working

Tags: python, c++, arduino, raspberry-pi

I need help trying to get a Raspberry pi to communicate with an Arduino using NRF24l01+.

Example files from nrf24 libraries don't run or compile; I've tried 5 libraries for both arduino and the pi, none work. But for now, i'll go along with the most detailed guide on this i was able to find: http://invent.module143.com/daskal_tutorial/rpi-3-tutorial-14-wireless-pi-to-arduino-communication-with-nrf24l01/

I'm running raspbian(from noobs). So far, i've done everything exactly as this guide has told me to do. When i run the program on the pi(with no sending arduino, just to test), the code runs into an error:

```
File "sendArduino.py", line 38
  if (n &gt; = 32 and n &lt;= 126):

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So i removed the if statement entirely, and un-indented the line of code in the if statement. When i run it now, i get a different error.

```
Traceback(most recent call last):
File "sendArduino.py", line 11, in <module>
  radio.begin(0, 17)
File "/home/pi/Desktop/NRF24L01/lib_nrf24.py", line 373, in begin
  self.spidev.open(0, csn_pin)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

After seeing that it was the SPI part that wasn't working, i went back and re-dowloaded the python spidev from the tutorial, but it gives the same errors.

I don't really know what to do here. In fact, all i want to do is send maybe 20 int valuesfr float values between an arduino and raspberry pi with these nrf24 modules. (preferably in python or cpp). I've already tried a bunch of other guides out there, i don't know what im doing wrong.

Comment: If you are exactly using `if (n &gt; = 32 and n &lt;= 126):`, it's obvious why it's not a valid syntax. It's just the html encoded string for `if (n >= 32 and n <= 126):`. Don't just copy/paste example codes.

Comment: so the errors on the greater/lesser than signs were due to the copypasting? good to know.

Comment: not only the copy/pasting, but the fact `&gt;` and `&lt;` are on that page due to a mistake on that webpage. You had to fix them to correct operators after copy/pasting.

Comment: The code still doesnt run and gives the second error after the changes.

Comment: @KamyarInfinity thanks man, your suggestion works for me!

Answer (score 0):

After a fresh morning and a few hours of troubleshooting/debugging, i got his code to work. It turns out, when i set SPI to 'on' in the pi menu>preferences, it doesn't actually do it. I had to change the config file to enable spi.

Comment: I should add: The code was also wrong. The arduino library default data rate is 2mbps, he set the one on the rpi to 1mbps. When i removed that and let it default back to 2, it worked. When i turned on SPI, i got the startup printout instead of syntax errors.

Comment: Hi, i'm having the same issue with the syntax but changing the config file doesn't work for me. got any idea what else it could be?